# Razor page giving me "The type or namespace name 'IBrowserFile' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I have been following the MS Documentation for "ASP.NET Core Blazor file uploads" at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0.

I have inserted the following code

By following the steps, I eventually run into an error at this line

```
private Dictionary<IBrowserFile, string> loadedFiles = new Dictionary<IBrowserFile, string>();
```

and get the error message

> The type or namespace name 'IBrowserFile' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I get the same error with `InputFileChangeEventArgs`.

I was wondering why this happens and how to fix it.

Comment: Have you looked at the `_Imports.razor` file to make sure everything is listed correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is only available in `.net5.0`, you may check your Framework version.

Comment: This worked. I had to change the target framework as well in the .csproj files!

Answer (score 0):

I very highly recommend upgrading.  It's a bit tricky, especially if you want to use CSS localization, but there are so many changes in Blazor this year that it's worth the effort.